# cannot delete shadow storage from powershell

Tags: powershell

My hard disk has three partitions c:(windows10), e:(windows 8.1) and g:\storage.

When I try to create a backup of c:\ & e:\ on g:\ the backup fails because drive g:\ has its shadow storage on drive e:\ instead of on itself.

This situation was created last month because I have created backups every month for the three past years.

I used the `vssadmin` command from elevated command prompt but there is no way to delete the shadow storage on drive E:\ but you can only see it.

So I have to use powershell in order to use something like 
PS `c:\windows\system32\>wmic shadowstorage delete` ... but I don't know the exact syntax after the verb delete (e.g. volume=E:)

How can I resolve this?

Comment: there's a wmi class `win32_shadowcopy` you could try. `(get-wmiobject win32_shadowcopy | where { $_.something -eq 'something' }).delete()` as you can see i left the filter empty for yourself to fill (change `$_.something` to a propertyname and `'something'` to a real string) so you can target the correct shadowcopy object. I don't know if that will work, but you can try. run only `get-wmiobject win32_shadowcopy` first to get a feeling

Comment: This is the same as https://serverfault.com/questions/526222/delete-shadow-copies-remotely

Answer (score 0):

#### There is no way to delete the shadow storage on drive E:\

Actually there is.

Use the following command:

```
vssadmin delete shadows /for=e: /all
```

---

#### Vssadmin delete shadows

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> vssadmin delete shadows /for=<ForVolumeSpec> [/oldest | /all | /shadow=<ShadowID>] [/quiet]
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> [image]
>
> **Remarks**
>
> ```
> You can delete only shadow copies that have the client-accessible type.
> ```
>
> **Examples**:
>
> To delete the oldest shadow copy of volume C, type:
>
> ```
> vssadmin delete shadows /for=c: /oldest
> ```

Source [Vssadmin delete shadows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788026%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)